# Stop a Linux Script with another Script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-s3, cron, centos

I guys, I have a problem, I had been configure some basic script to send files to AWS in windows to backup the files for 8 hours with the task scheduler but now I have to do it in Linux (Centos y Ubuntu), the script is basically  this " aws sync "PC folder" "AWS bucket" "and is launched with crontab but how can I run this script only for 8 hours then make it stop it automatically, How can i do this? please Help

Comment: More info on the script would help to solve this question. Is it a bash script? Which user is running the script (root because it's in cron?)

Comment: Hi neonfuz, yes is a bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the only aws process running on the machine, it could be as simple as writing a script that runs

```
pkill aws
```

and schedule it 8 hours after the start time.

Note this searches for any process named aws and kills it, so if other aws commands are running they would be killed too. Killing by process name isn't the most reliable, usually killing by PID is better but I would need to know more details about your script to know how to get the PID, and where to store it.